# Does summoning the Poro King remove Poro Toss counts?

Tags: league-of-legends

In the Legend of the Poro King game mode, I know by the counters in the upper corner that summoning the Poro King is caused by landing 10 Poro Tosses as a team.

But, when the Poro King is finally killed, I know my team's Poro Toss count is returned to zero, but what about the other teams' Poro Toss count?

Secondly, do Poro Tosses connected by either team count towards the Poro Toss count while either Poro King is active?

Comment: For the second question, I'm inclined to say 'no', because I have not seen both teams' Poro Kings active at once.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After playing a couple more games and watching the Poro Score intently, I can say the following with certainty:

1. The Poro King only resets the summoning teams Poro Score.
2. Poro Tosses when you have a Poro King do not count toward a new total, but can still be used to damage and rush the enemy. This combined with 'To The King!' allows for very effective hit and run tactics. When the Poro King is dispelled, that team's Poro Score is set to zero.
3. The Poro King will absorb Poro Tosses that enter his circle of influence. Any Poro Toss landed while the other team's Poro King is active do not count to your existing total. When the Poro King is dispelled, that other team's Poro Score is returned to the value it was before he was summoned.

Comment: exactly what I experienced